# Check if a list of buttons have texts

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I would like to check, if the buttons appended to a list have texts, and give an oportunity to restart the game if all contain texts. I could not check, if the buttons have texts, and, since they were created by a for loop I could not check for it one-by-one. Is there a way to check it like this, or shall I try something else? I apologize, if the answer is evident, I could not find it elsewhere and I am a beginner.

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial


class ButtonTest():
  def __init__(self, master):
    self.parent = master

    self.buttons_list = []

    for i in range(5):
        for j in range(3):

            button_num = i * 3 + j
            button = tk.Button(self.parent, height=6, width=12)
            button.grid(row=i, column=j)


            button.bind("<Button-1>", partial(self.click, button_num))


            self.buttons_list.append(button)


    self.counter = []

    #def check_winner():


  def click(self, button_num, event):
    this_button = self.buttons_list[button_num]
    the_actual_counter = len(self.counter)

    if the_actual_counter % 2 == 0:
        this_button["text"] = "X"


    else:
        this_button["text"] = "O"

    self.counter.append("element")

master = tk.Tk()
BT = ButtonTest(master)
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: `all(button['text'] for button in self.buttons_list)`

Answer (score 0):

If L=[b1,b2,b3] (which you create by appending) then,

```
def check_winner:
    c=0
    for i in L:
        if i.cget("text")=="":
            print("GAME OVER") # or whatever you want
            c=1
            break
    if c==0:
        print("PLAY AGAIN")
```

Comment: That will print game over for *every* button without text

Comment: The break statement just slipped out of mind. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With `buttons=[bttn1, bttn2, etc.]`(or whatever you call them) then you can do this, using `all`:

```
def check_winner:
    again=all(i.cget("text") for i in buttons)
    if again:
        print("play again?") # or whatever
    else:
        print("game over!") # or whatever
```